# Sending a pointer with MPI

Tags: mpi, shared-memory, mmap

I would like to send a pointer with MPI. When searching, it says that I should never do this, so I am open to other solutions for my problem as well. I am trying to implement a distributed shared memory library on top of MPI.

For example, suppose we have a large array with virtual addresses 0x1000000000000 - 0x3fffffffffffff.

Having three processes, process 0 stores the values of 0x1000000000000 - 0x1fffffffffffff
and protects 0x2000000000000 - 0x3fffffffffffff

process 1 protects 0x1000000000000 - 0x1fffffffffffff, 0x3000000000000 - 0x3fffffffffffff
and stores 0x2000000000000 - 0x2fffffffffffff.

etc.

Whenever we try to read from this array in a position that is protected, we catch the segfault, use the address to calculate which processor owns that part, and copy the desired data.

However, for this to work we need to allocate the region 0x1000000000000 - 0x3fffffffffffff
on each process. To make this (more) portable, I want to use mmap(NULL, ...) on process 0, and then send the address we get from this to the other processes. Is there a way to send this address, or a cleaner solution?

Comment: This is not how MPI works. `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` is likely the closest thing you are looking for.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet MPI_Win_allocate_shared does not work with physically distributed memory if I understand correctly. It should be possible to achieve something like this, because Samhita from Bharath Ramesh's PhD dissertation does this. That dissertation does not include many implementation details however, and interfaces with the hardware directly.

Comment: You can send an address: use the `MPI_Aint` datatype. However, how are the other processes going to allocate at that address? It sounds very dangerous.

Comment: are you trying to implement a MPI+X library? in this case, you can MPI+MPI (pt2pt and collective between nodes, one sided within one node). If you simply want to implement a distributed library on top of MPI, then why use pointers (that would only work within a node) instead of messages?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet It is supposed to become a part of a compiler that auto-parallises code for clusters. I would like to use pointers because then I can integrate it into the private heap manager and then reuse the existing backend for multithreading. I am going to have a look at MPI+MPI.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thanks, I completely overlooked that. The other processes will allocate with mmap and MAP_FIXED, aborting if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a pointer using MPI_Send by sending the binary representation of it which is unsigned long long int in 64 bit operating systems which means the datatype argument that is passed to MPI_Send should be MPI_UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG. If you want to use mmap in windows you can use my repo from https://github.com/CoderRC/libmingw32_extended .